# Not sure what this data format this is (if any)

Tags: php, parsing, types, dataformat

[Data](http://pastebin.com/cduYkZdY)

Anyone know what data format/structure this is (if any)? I want to parse this game data with PHP but I don't really want to build a 'custom' one. If a parser already exists for this kind of data I'd like to use that instead.

Thanks for any tips or suggestions in general.

Comment: This doesn't look like any other data format. It might be processed XML, but then again it could be processed anything. You'll have to write your own parser.

Comment: Have you contacted Riot Games to see if they have a PHP client codebase and a published API?

Comment: They don't, that's why I'm doing it myself :)

Comment: Looks like a human readable (ish) dump of a variable/variables to me, something like `print_r` or `var_dump`. It looks like a serialization of ActionScipt objects, although not in any format I know of or can find reference to - it looks like it would be something of a nightmare to parse. And I have +1'ed this to counter the un-explained (and slightly unreasonable) -1.

Comment: Looks like the result of `ObjectUtil.toString(…)` to me (disclaimer: it has been years since I wrote any ActionScript), "parsing" that yourself in PHP will probably be quicker/easier than finding something ready-made (in PHP).

Comment: @DaveRandom Thank you for the support, it is appreciated.

salathe If you wrote that as an answer I would have accepted it, since it seems to be the closest answer. The answer by Timur is similar so I will accept his.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`10/29/2011 16:44:57.899 [DEBUG]` - This is only a debug information, formatted as someone comfortable to read it. It is may be an output of Java application.

Comment: Maybe it's a custom data format, considering that data is sent to the server as you see it.

Comment: It seems like it's not a recognized format from anywhere so I will accept this as an answer for now. Thanks.